# What is the best way to store grid coordinates in C?

Tags: c

I am currently writing a game of battleship as a project for a class. What is the best way to store coordinates for ship locations? The ocean is a 10x10 grid square with letters going horizontally and numbers vertically. I need to store the coordinates of each ship. For example, the carrier has 5 spaces so A1, B1, C1, D1, and E1. If I do this in an array, I would somehow have to break up the A1 into a char and an int. Correct? Is there a better way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a structure:

```
struct point{
    int m_vertical;
    char m_horizon;
}
```

any way you need to do some effort before you ask a question. 
Please do some effort and try to search and dig in the webs before asking.
good luck

Comment: Thank you! I think that type of data structure is exactly what I am looking for. I will create an array of structs. I didn't know how to formulate my question for a search and I am new to programming. I kept using the wrong keywords in Google and did not find what I was looking for. I suspected a struct would be right but I had no idea.

Comment: Hi @matt - My pleasure. If you think my answer was useful for you, please mark it as a useful answer (by pushing on the ^ up arrow near my answer).
Good luck

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do here is translate those letters and numbers into array positions.

Take the example of `E2`. E is the 5th letter of the alphabet, so it could represent the 5th row of your ocean. The same goes for the numbers, although you don't need any translation there, so 2 is the 2nd column. Now, if you remember that array indexes start at 0, the 5th row is actually at the 4th index, and the 2nd column is at the 1st index. So, `E2` represents `ocean[4][1]` (or `ocean[1][4]`, depending on your representation);

With that being said, to turn something like `E2` into coordinates you can do something like this:

```
char pos[2] = {'E', '2'};
int col = pos[0] - 'A';
int row = pos[1] - '0';

// now you can access your ocean with something like ocean[col][row]
```

What I'm doing here is taking the ASCII code of the letter E and subtracting the ACSII code of the letter A from it. The same for '2' and '0'. This works because ASCII codes from 'A' to 'Z' go from 65 to 90, in order, and ASCII codes for '0' to '9' go from 48 to 57.

Comment: I wrote a function to actually convert the letter to a number using a switch case which does work. Now I know that I need a struct to store it.